# Flex - ExternalInterface.available

Tags: jsp, apache-flex, flex4.5

The definition for ExternalInterface.available goes like this:

"The ExternalInterface.available property indicates whether the current Flash Player is in a container that offers an external interface."

What is the exact meaning of the above definition? Also, when the value of ExternalInterface.available becomes false?

In my application, I embed the generated swf file in a JSP, also i'll have the related javascript functions in it. I'll call the functions from mxml using ExternalInterface.call method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container for the Flash Player is usually a browser. If the Browser provides a JavaScript VM, then you could let the player communicate with website and vice versa.

But if you'd run the SWF in the standalone player, there would no External interface available and your JavaScript calls wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks Florian. I'd tried a sample mxml. When I open via browser it was true. When I directly opened the swf, the value was false. Now I understood the definition.